# C# WindowHandles works better than Java GetWindowHandles

Tags: java, c#, selenium

Ok so i continue to convert my C# framework to Java

In C# , Driver.WindowHandles returns a count of 2, which is correct, so i tell it to select 'last' and it works great.

In Java the Driver.GetWindowHandles returns a count of only 1, which messes up my script as i need to access the 2nd window

Can anyone do a method in Java that mimics the way the c# method does it (as it seems to work better than whatever the Java equivalent does)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the driver a Firefox driver?

Comment: No, chromedriver